Building `gnu-riscv-toolchain` in a podman container
I'm trying to build the riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc toolchain from https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain in a container, but the build fails and I have no idea why.
Here is my ContainerFile:
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    curl \
    git \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    autotools-dev \
    python3 \
    libmpc-dev \
    libmpfr-dev \
    libgmp-dev \
    gawk \
    bison \
    flex \
    texinfo \
    gperf \
    libtool \
    patchutils \
    bc \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libexpat-dev \
    ninja-build

ENV CARGO_HOME /root/.cargo 
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"
RUN rustup target add riscv32i-unknown-none-elf
RUN cargo install cargo-binutils && rustup component add llvm-tools-preview

WORKDIR /app

RUN git clone https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain.git
ENV PATH="/opt/riscv/bin:${PATH}"
RUN (cd riscv-gnu-toolchain; ./configure --prefix=/opt/riscv --with-arch=rv32gc --with-abi=ilp32d)
RUN (cd riscv-gnu-toolchain; make linux)

And here are the last few lines of the outptu
g++  -fno-PIE -c   -g -O2   -DIN_GCC -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wconditionally-supported -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fno-PIE -I. -I. -I../.././gcc/gcc -I../.././gcc/gcc/. -I../.././gcc/gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libcpp/include -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libcody  -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd -I../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libbacktrace   -o insn-emit-1.o -MT insn-emit-1.o -MMD -MP -MF ./.deps/insn-emit-1.TPo insn-emit-1.cc
g++  -fno-PIE -c   -g -O2   -DIN_GCC -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wconditionally-supported -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fno-PIE -I. -I. -I../.././gcc/gcc -I../.././gcc/gcc/. -I../.././gcc/gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libcpp/include -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libcody  -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd -I../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libbacktrace   -o insn-emit-2.o -MT insn-emit-2.o -MMD -MP -MF ./.deps/insn-emit-2.TPo insn-emit-2.cc
g++  -fno-PIE -c   -g -O2   -DIN_GCC -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wconditionally-supported -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fno-PIE -I. -I. -I../.././gcc/gcc -I../.././gcc/gcc/. -I../.././gcc/gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libcpp/include -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libcody  -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd -I../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libbacktrace   -o insn-emit-3.o -MT insn-emit-3.o -MMD -MP -MF ./.deps/insn-emit-3.TPo insn-emit-3.cc
g++  -fno-PIE -c   -g -O2   -DIN_GCC -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wconditionally-supported -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fno-PIE -I. -I. -I../.././gcc/gcc -I../.././gcc/gcc/. -I../.././gcc/gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libcpp/include -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libcody  -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd -I../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libbacktrace   -o insn-emit-4.o -MT insn-emit-4.o -MMD -MP -MF ./.deps/insn-emit-4.TPo insn-emit-4.cc
g++  -fno-PIE -c   -g -O2   -DIN_GCC -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wconditionally-supported -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fno-PIE -I. -I. -I../.././gcc/gcc -I../.././gcc/gcc/. -I../.././gcc/gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libcpp/include -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libcody  -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd -I../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libbacktrace   -o insn-emit-5.o -MT insn-emit-5.o -MMD -MP -MF ./.deps/insn-emit-5.TPo insn-emit-5.cc
g++  -fno-PIE -c   -g -O2   -DIN_GCC -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wconditionally-supported -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fno-PIE -I. -I. -I../.././gcc/gcc -I../.././gcc/gcc/. -I../.././gcc/gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libcpp/include -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libcody  -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd -I../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libbacktrace   -o insn-emit-6.o -MT insn-emit-6.o -MMD -MP -MF ./.deps/insn-emit-6.TPo insn-emit-6.cc
g++  -fno-PIE -c   -g -O2   -DIN_GCC -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wconditionally-supported -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fno-PIE -I. -I. -I../.././gcc/gcc -I../.././gcc/gcc/. -I../.././gcc/gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libcpp/include -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libcody  -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd -I../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/gcc/../libbacktrace   -o insn-emit-7.o -MT insn-emit-7.o -MMD -MP -MF ./.deps/insn-emit-7.TPo insn-emit-7.cc
g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1198: insn-emit-7.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/app/riscv-gnu-toolchain/build-gcc-linux-stage1/gcc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:4673: all-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/app/riscv-gnu-toolchain/build-gcc-linux-stage1'
make: *** [Makefile:472: stamps/build-gcc-linux-stage1] Error 2

Does anyone know what causes this failure?

Out of memory probably. The compiler needs more memory than allowed by the container

@AndreyTurkin I don't think that's it. AFAIK podman containers don't have memory limits by default. If you do put a memory limit on your container and it exceeds it, the build fails with OOM error

You're going to have to get some details on what signal killed cc1plus and what sent it. I don't know what logs you'll get in a default ubuntu container though.
